# Putting an optional <md-card> inside a component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to make an optional md-card with Angular 2 Material... I've made a component that has a bunch of content inside a card and I want to be able to toggle the card style on and off with a boolean that is passed into the component.

Because the md-card directive doesn't support this I've tried just using the underlying CSS class directly by doing `[class.mat-card]="myBool"`. This only works if there has been a `<md-card>` present on the page before or else the `mat-card` style will not have been injected to the DOM...

I can achieve this by duplicating my content but I want to avoid that... for example:

```
<md-card *ngIf="myBool">
    [My Content]
</md-card>
<div *ngIf="!myBool">
    [My Duplicated Content]
</div>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work:

```
<md-card [ngClass]="{'classA': myBool, 'classB': !myBool}">
    [My Content]
</md-card>
```

Regards, 
Diego.